# CASE Syntax error when > is used in the WHEN clause

Tags: sql

This Query runs fine when I do not have the ">" symbol in the WHEN clause however I need this to work when the ProposalDate is any date later than '2017-04-10 00:00:00.000'. Not sure why I am getting a Syntax error when I add the > into the WHEN clause.

```
SELECT *,
    CASE ProposalDate WHEN > '2017-04-10 00:00:00.000'
        THEN (OrderTotal - ProposalWholesalePrice) +
             (ProposalWholesalePrice * 1.02)
        ELSE OrderTotal    
    END "New_OrderTotal"
FROM webservices.dbo.DT_Open_Orders_Baseprice
WHERE ProposalSerialNumber = '639036'
```

Comment: `Case when x >y then` or `case x when y then`.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL `CASE` expression [has two forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql):

- The simple `CASE` expression, and
- The searched `CASE` expression.

Simple `CASE`, i.e. `CASE ProposalDate WHEN ...` cannot be used with comparison operators; you need a searched `CASE` instead:

```
SELECT
    *
,   CASE
        WHEN ProposalDate > '2017-04-10 00:00:00.000'
        THEN (OrderTotal - ProposalWholesalePrice) + (ProposalWholesalePrice * 1.02)
        ELSE OrderTotal
    END "New_OrderTotal"
FROM webservices.dbo.DT_Open_Orders_Baseprice
WHERE ProposalSerialNumber = '639036'
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried to put the "WHEN" before the column name?
For example:

```
SELECT *, CASE WHEN ProposalDate > '2017-04-10 00:00:00.000'

THEN (OrderTotal - ProposalWholesalePrice) + (ProposalWholesalePrice * 1.02) ELSE OrderTotal

END "New_OrderTotal" FROM webservices.dbo.DT_Open_Orders_Baseprice WHERE ProposalSerialNumber = '639036'
```

Answer (score 0):

The shorthand `case` syntax doesn't use any operators, just a series of values which are evaluated with the `=` condition. If you want to use other operators, you have to use the full `case` syntax:

```
SELECT *, 
       CASE WHEN ProposalDate > '2017-04-10 00:00:00.000' 
            THEN (OrderTotal - ProposalWholesalePrice) + 
                 (ProposalWholesalePrice * 1.02) 
           ELSE OrderTotal 
       END "New_OrderTotal"
FROM   webservices.dbo.DT_Open_Orders_Baseprice 
WHERE  ProposalSerialNumber = '639036'
```